# virtual host config file not redirecting http to https

Tags: apache

I have the problem of redirecting the http to https but all the information/tutorials and descriptions are not working. We are using Apache2 on a Debian machine and this is the conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName assets.xxx.it
        ServerAlias assets.xxx.it
        DocumentRoot /var/www/assets/eit_resource_manager_frontend/build
        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        RedirectMatch ^(.*)$ https://assets.xxx.it$1   
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName assets.xxx.it
  ServerAlias assets.xxx.it

  Protocols h2 http/1.1
<Directory "/var/www/assets/eit_resource_manager_frontend/build">
RewriteEngine on
#Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
#Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.theml [L]
</Directory>
  

  # SSL Configuration

  # Other Apache Configuration

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/assets.xxx.it/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/assets.xxx.it/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

After any change in the file I restart the server but the HTTP is not redirected to HTTPS. I have tried different implementation with same poor result.
For further information, the login page is on assets.xxx.it/login and the redirect from "/" to "/login" is handled inside the app (via React Router)

Any suggestions?

Comment: **1** if you connect directly to https does it respond ok?  **2** do you receive the redirect response from your http connection?  **3** what do logs say?  **4** put your LogLevel to some trace level and run tests again.  **5** do you have Listen on ports 80 and 443?  **6** since you seem to redirect everything, you could try `RedirectPermanent`.  **7** have you loaded  the alias module for RedirectMatch. **8** you could try with the rewrite module instead of the alias.

Comment: 1 Yes. 2 No: when using http://assets.xxx.it the website shows up correctly but on the URL it is marked as "unsafe". 3 I am afraid not to be able to gain info from the error.log  4  what are the commands? 5 if you are talking about the vh config file, it is copied above? 6 already tried. 7 if I understood it correctly, no I have not, as it is not in the list of available modules (like 'rewrite', for example) 8 already tried with same poor result.... but probably I did not use the correct sintax, as the tutorials are not very clear, so if you could please provide an example I can make a try

Comment: Web site debug hints:   **2** in your browser, bring up the dev tools (F12 in Chrome).  In that new window, go to Network.   It will show you all exchanges between your site and your browser.  It should say you received a redirect code (ex. 301 or 302).  If you do not get a redirect, that means you did not configure your apache properly.  **4** DebugLevel in your config file, look it up.  **5** Outsite your VH, you require `Listen 80` and `Listen 443` somewhere.  Otherwise, Apache does not listen to the ports.  **7** You require to load mod_alias to use RewriteMatch.  [...]

Comment: **7** without mod_alias, RewriteMatch will never work.  If you only have mod_rewrite, you will have to use RewriteRule.  **8** there are a **LOT** of questions regarding rewrites for http -> https on this site, hundreds probably.  Research is your salvation.  :)

Comment: without looking unpolite, if I had found an answer I 'd have not opened a new thread. I found several ways for redirecting (with rewrite module, redirect, redirectMatch) and this is quite confusing if you do not have a DevOps background, which is evident I do not have. So writing that "Outsite your VH, you require Listen 80 and Listen 443 somewhere" is not helpful: WHERE should I write it and with which syntax? I heard of httpaccess or httpd config files that do NOT exists on the server. As regarding the 301-302 I do not have any in the network but this was evident since there is no redirect

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When creating the SSL certificate with `certbot` and the Apache plugin, a SSL config file was created, so we came up with having a file for vh 80 created by us, a file for vh 443 created by us, and a file for both 80 and 443 generated while creating the certificate.

As said, this file had instructions for both port 80 and 443 but, despite the fact that we asked for the redirect while creating the certificate, there was not such an instruction in this `conf` file. So we added the `RedirectMatch` instruction and it worked. We also deleted the vh 443 conf file that we had created and it went on working.

After other search I have also understood that the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` in the `Directory` tag are just there if you want to use the `.htaccess` file in the repo folder for a more grained control.